# can anyone figure out the bug in my code?

Tags: javascript

The function is supposed to solve the following problem, but there is something wrong in it.

The problem:
Repeat a given string str (first argument) for num times (second argument). Return an empty string if num is not a positive number.

```
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  var result = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    result += 'str';
  }
  return result;
}

repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```

Comment: Yes, it’s bug not pug

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: You are repeating hardcoded string ```'str'``` instead string ```str```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to add the old string to the new one and don't forget the space between them

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  var result = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    result = result + str + ' ';
  }
  return result;
}

repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

two problems.  first 'str' will give you a literal. you want the variable str.  second, once you have the result you need to display it.

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  var result = '';

  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    result += str;
  }
  return result;
}

var result = repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you're not returning if the `num` is not positive. Second, it should be `str` and not 'str' if you want to repeat the variable.

```js
function repeatStringNumTimes(str, num) {
  var result = '';
  if (num < 1) return; //return if num is not postive
  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
    result += str;
  }
  return result;
}
var res = repeatStringNumTimes("abc", 3);
console.log(res)
```